Customize login form Microsoft Remote Desktop WebClient
I was able to modify the old login form by editing the aspx and css files, but I upgraded to the new html5 to use remote desktop in the browser but it seems that the content is built at runtime, I only managed to change the login background by css. Is it possible to edit the project?
